# Database model structure django - through models

Tags: django, database

Ok - lets say I have a setup where I have a set of people and a set of skills and a set of levels.

Each skill has a subset of levels associated with it - different subset is possible for each skill. Each person can perform a subset of the skills at a subset of the levels. Each skill that a person offers a particular level has a price associated with it.

E.g. Person A can do skills karate and creative writing. He offers karate at black belt level for £40 and red belt level for £30 and creative writing at beginner level for £25.

Here is how I have setup without level.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, through='SkillOffered')

class Skill(models.Model):
    ...

class SkillOffered(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    price = models.DemicalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

But how can I include level? Can I add a foreign key to level with a through model to skill offered. Is there a way this could be viewed in the admin so that you would be able to edit the list of skills and levels that a person offers from the person admin page?

Answer (score 0):

you should create a Level class linked to Skill class by a m2m relation. And replace skill attribute in SkillOffered by a skill_level attribute.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class Skill(models.Model):
   ...
   levels = models.ManyToManyField(Levels, through='SkillLevels')

class Level(models.Model):
   ...

class SkillLevels (models.Model):
   skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
   level = models.ForeignKey(Level)

class SkillOffered(models.Model):
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
   skill_level = models.ForeignKey(SkillLevels)
   price = models.DemicalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @jcs, what does SkillLevels do? ForeignKey to Skill and m2m to Level?

Comment: Yes exactly. It joins your skill 'karate' with levels 'blue belt", "red belt"... then the skilloffered is the combination of the two, with a specific price. Because the price is specific to the combination skill/level not just the skill.

Comment: Look. I just edited classes Person and SkillLevels. Person is now linked to SkillOffered, SkillOffered is linked to SkillLevels which is the combination table for Skill and Level.

Comment: also, does this mean that the skills attribute on person should be a link to SkillLevel not Skill?

Comment: Person won't have a skill attribute as it is regular foreignkey from skilloffered. One person can have multiple 'skilloffers' but one skilloffer as only one price and one person.